# Ruby-Heroku how to create procfile

Tags: ruby, heroku, procfile

i am trying heroku for my hobyst app. i deployed my app. but idk what is procfile or anything.

i saw 'web:' like thats things but i didnt.

Im starting my app with pry. have in my gemfile.

my console line:

```
c:> pry -r ./filelocation/app.rb

[1] pry(main)> bot = TwitchBot.new

[2] pry(main)> bot.run
```

can anyone help me about that. how to be procfile for this console line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same as you do in pry with a simple one-liner:

```
ruby -r ./filelocation/app.rb -e "TwitchBot.new.run"
```

... and this is something that could go to your `Procfile`.

However, it might be better to use `worker:` instead of `web:`, because otherwise Heroku will assume it's a HTTP server and will accordingly perform some healthchecks, leading to frequent restarts of your app. With `worker:` it should not.

Comment: i added worker: ruby -r ./ruby.rb -e "TwitchBot.new.run" true ?